# Python - Search multiple keywords via csv file and get first URL from BING.com result and save it in CSV

Tags: python, csv, search

I am trying to write a python script that will search multiple keywords via input.csv file one by one and get the first search result URL from BING.com respectively and save it in the CSV file.

**Input.CSV file content**

| Keyword | URL |
| --- | --- |
| Facebook | --- |
| Twitter | --- |
| Etc. | --- |

**Desired CSV Output:**

| Keyword | URL |
| --- | --- |
| Facebook | [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) |
| Twitter | [www.twitter.com](http://www.twitter.com) |

I had tried to do this via Google search (googlesearch module) in python but want to achieve it using BeautifulSoup so that I can change the search engine via specifying a url in the code, e.g. https://www.bing.com/search?&q= or https://www.duckduckgo.com/search?&q=

I am able to get the search result in the console but for the 2nd keyword only.

**Current CSV Output:**

| Keyword | URL |
| --- | --- |
| Facebook | blank |
| Twitter | [www.twitter.com](http://www.twitter.com) |

Following code is working

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml
import csv
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

keywords = pd.read_excel("D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Python\\Test\\duck\\keywords.xls")

for keyword in keywords['Keywords']:
    print(keyword)

response = requests.get(
    "https://www.bing.com/search?form=QBRE&q="  + keyword,
    headers=headers).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

for link in soup.find_all('.b_algo h2 a'):
    print(link.get('href'))

for container in soup.select('.b_algo h2 a', limit=1):
  links = container['href']
  print(links)
```

**Output:**

[image: Working output]

But when I am trying use array but it's not working: Following is the WIP code so far.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml
import csv
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

keywords = pd.read_csv('D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Python\\Test\\duck\\input.csv', header=0, index_col=None)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['keyword', 'url'])

for i in keywords['keyword']: 
    url = "https://www.bing.com/search?form=QBRE&q=" + i, headers=headers).text
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoupBeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
    for j in soup.select('.b_algo h2 a', limit=1):
        link = j['href']
        print(link)
    df = df.append({'keyword': i, 'url': j}, ignore_index=True)     

df.to_csv(r'D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Python\\Test\\duck\\final_dataset.csv', index=False)

input(" press close to exit ")
```

But it's not working. Can someone please help me in fixing the code. Since I am beginner in Python, if help me with the complete working code too.

Comment: There are clearly syntax errors here. Fix them. Then identify "what is not working". And then please try asking agin. With a clear question on how we can help

Comment: @clmno, I have edited the post with all the details and what's working and not working and my desired output. Please let me know if you need more info on this,

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the code myself. Now I am getting the individual URLs from the Bing search results and I am able to save the same in a CSV file.

If someone is looking for the working code then here it is.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml
import csv
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

keywords = pd.read_csv('D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Python\\Test\\duck\\input.csv', header=0, index_col=None)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['keyword', 'url'])

for keyword in keywords['keywords']:
    print(keyword)
    response = requests.get("https://www.bing.com/search?form=QBRE&q="  + keyword, headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
    for j in soup.select('.b_algo h2 a', limit=1):
        link = j['href']
        print(link)
    df = df.append({'keyword': keyword, 'url': link}, ignore_index=True)        

df.to_csv(r'D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Python\\Test\\duck\\final_dataset.csv', index=False)

input(" press close to exit ")
```

CSV Output:

| keyword | url |
| --- | --- |
| facebook | https://www.facebook.com/ |
| twitter | https://twitter.com/?lang=en-in |